Spreading props with conditional props after omitting
I have a component which conditionally accepts either of two props using never like this:
type Props = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
} & (
  | {
      education?: string;
      profession?: never;
    }
  | {
      education?: never;
      profession?: string;
    }
);

export function X(props: Props) {
  return null;
}

Now if I have another component that reuses this first component but with omitting a property like name like so:
export function Y(props: Omit<Props, 'name'>) {
  return <X name="John" {...props} />;
}

I get the following error:
Type '{ age: number; education?: string | undefined; profession?: string | undefined; name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.
  Type '{ age: number; education?: string | undefined; profession?: string | undefined; name: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ education?: undefined; profession?: string | undefined; }'.
    Types of property 'education' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'. 

If I remove the Omit, it works.
How can I omit a prop from props containing conditional props such as in the example?

Conditional type OmitName to ensure that when omitting name.
TypeScript preserves the mutually exclusive logic between education and profession without breaking their type constraints:
type Props = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
} & (
  | {
      education?: string;
      profession?: never;
    }
  | {
      education?: never;
      profession?: string;
    }
);


type OmitName<T> = T extends { name: any } ? Omit<T, 'name'> : T;

export function X(props: Props) {
  return null;
}

export function Y(props: OmitName<Props>) {
  return <X name="John" {...props} />;
}


I would replace any with unknown and yes that works. But can you provide an explanation? I dont see the difference between Omit<Props, 'name'> in the original post and type OmitName<T> = T extends { name: any } ? Omit<T, 'name'> : T;

Reason:
The difference is that Omit<Props, 'name'> flattens the union, causing TypeScript to lose the mutual exclusivity between education and profession.
OmitName uses a conditional type that distributes over the union, ensuring the exclusivity is preserved by applying Omit to each part of the union separately, keeping the constraints intact.

You need to handle the union logic manually after omitting the name prop. So, you can try to extract the conditional types into union and combine the results back to it.
type OmitNameFromProps = (
  | Omit<{ name: string; age: number } & { education?: string; profession?: never }, 'name'>
  | Omit<{ name: string; age: number } & { education?: never; profession?: string }, 'name'>
);

So, you can use it as:
export function Y(props: OmitNameFromProps) {
  return <X name="John" {...(props as Props)} />;
}


Is there a way to do it without repeating the entire props over and over? The X and Y components are not close to each other and X is not aware of Y

@RamiElwan answer below mentioned it, I guess it is accepted answer for you.

Yes marked it, thanks!
